# Custom Decimal Function

Tags: javascript

I want to make a function, this is what I need.

If a number starts with a 0, give that number a max of 6 decimals.
If not (number starts with 1,2,3...), give that number a max of 2 decimals.

```
$567.45321432 > $567.45
$65.3 > 65.30
$0.1 > 0.100000
$0.00003 > 0.000030
```

This is what I've got so far. the `firstnumb = 0` when it must be `5`. Any idea what may cause this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
var num = 544.3;
var str = num.toString();
var firstnumb = str.charAt(0);
    if (firstnumb = "0") {
        alert("2 Decimals");
        var numdecimal = parseInt(str, 10).toFixed(2);
    } else {
        alert("6 Decimals");
        var numdecimal = parseInt(str, 10).toFixed(6);
    } 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hey there and thanks for asking a question at SO. It's important to understand that this isn't a code-writing service, but rather a resource for getting *help*. As it seems like you haven't really done any research and/or coding of your own just yet, it's likely that your question will be downvoted or closed. Please take a few seconds to edit it, providing something for us to help you correct.

Comment: `.toFixed` maybe?!

Comment: @TylerRoper Hey Tyler, I've edited my question I hope it helps

Comment: @Reginald1234 To compare equality, you'd use `a == b` or `a === b`. However you're doing `a = b`, which *assigns* values, rather than comparing them. Try `if (firstnumb === "0")` instead.

Comment: Why can't you do this? `(x | 0) > 0 ? Math.round(x*1e2)*1e-2 : Math.round(x*1e6)*1e-6 ` ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Tyler Roper explained in the comments, you should use `===` instead of `=` since the later one is for assignments. Also, instead of `parseInt` you should use `parseFloat` because you are using floating numbers not integers.

```js
var num = 544.3;
var str = num.toString();
var firstnumb = str.charAt(0);
    if (firstnumb === "0") {
        console.log("6 Decimals");
        var numdecimal = parseFloat(str, 10).toFixed(6);
        alert( numdecimal );
    } else {
        console.log("2 Decimals");
        var numdecimal = parseFloat(str, 10).toFixed(2);
        alert( numdecimal );
    }
```